# 'Unable to deserialize XML body with root name 'Envelope' and root namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' (for operation '')

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Unable to deserialize XML body with root name 'Envelope' and root namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' (for operation 'notify' and contract ('IPush',  'http://www.ffffff.org/uuu/2003/05/beta')) using DataContractSerializer. Ensure that the type corresponding to the XML is added to the known types collection of the service.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
  <ResponseId xmlns="http://www.mhotel.com/"/>
  </soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <ns3:NotifRQ Status="yes" Token="ggggg" xmlns:ns2="http://www.yyyyyy.com/"     xmlns:ns3="http://www.ffffff.org/uuu/">
   </ns3:NotifRQ>
```

```
   [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.ffffff.org/uuu/")]
   public class HotelResNotifRQ
   {
    public HotelResNotifRQ()
    {
        NotifRQ = new NotifRQ();
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "NotifRQ")]
    public NotifRQ NotifRQ{ get; set; }
}


  [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.ffffff.org/uuu/")]
  public class NotifRQ
  {
    [DataMember(Name = "Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Did you add the type "to the known types"?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the type `NotifRQ` to the known types of `HotelResNotifRQ`'s datacontract.

Citing from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The KnownTypeAttribute class allows you to specify, in advance, the types that should be included for consideration during deserialization.

So consider doing the following:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.ffffff.org/uuu/")]
[KnownType(typeof(NotifRQ))] // add NotifRQ as a known type
public class HotelResNotifRQ
{
    public HotelResNotifRQ()
    {
        NotifRQ = new NotifRQ();
    }

    ...
```